# integrate zipkin and kafka in async spring boot microservices

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices, zipkin

I developed some spring microservices in which they communicate together.  and I used kafka in them. now I wanna add zipkin to trace requests how can I integrate kafka and zipkin in these microservices to see kafka spans in zipkin traces?

I trtied to request to one microservice which put something on kafka (producer) then another microservice will read that data (consumer) I cannot see consumer's data in zipkin traces